# Vertica COPY + FLEX table

Tags: copy, vertica

I want to load on a flex table a log in which each record is composed by some fields + a JSON, the format is the following:

```
"concorde-fe";"DETAILS.SHOWN";"1bcilyejs6d4w";"2017-01-31T00:00:04.801Z";"2017-01-31T00:00:04.714Z";"{"requestedFrom":"BUTTON","tripId":{"request":3003926837969,"mac":"v01162450701"}}"
```

and (after many tries) I'm using the COPY command with a CSV parser in this way:

```
COPY schema.flex_table from local 'C:\temp/test.log' parser fcsvparser(delimiter=';',header=false, trim=true, type='traditional')
```

in this way all is loaded correctly except the JSON, that is skipped and left empty.

Is there a way to load also the JSON as a string?

HINT: just for test puposes, I noticed that if in the JSON I put a '\' before every '"' in the log, the loading runs smoothly, but unfortunately I cannot modify the content of the log.

Answer (score 0):

Not without modifying the file beforehand - or writing your own UDParser function.

It clearly is a strange format: CSV (well, semicolon delimited and with double quotes as string enclosers), until the children appear - which are stored with a leading double quote and a trailing double quote; doubly nested with curly braces - JSON type, ok. But you have double quotes (not doubled) within the JSON encoding - any parser would go astray on those.

You'll have to write a program (ideally in C) to remove the curly braces, to remove the column names in the JSON code and leave just a CSV line

So, from the line (the backslash at the end means an escaped newline, meaning that the three lines you see are actually one line, for readability)

```
"concorde-fe";"DETAILS.SHOWN";"1bcilyejs6d4w";"2017-01-31T00:00:04.801Z"; \
"2017-01-31T00:00:04.714Z"; \
"{"requestedFrom":"BUTTON","tripId":{"request":3003926837969,"mac":"v01162450701"}}"
```

you make (title line with column names, then data line)

```
col1;col2;col3;timestampz1;\
timestampz2;requestedfrom;tripid_request;tripid_mac
"concorde-fe";"DETAILS.SHOWN";"1bcilyejs6d4w";"2017-01-31T00:00:04.801Z"; \
"2017-01-31T00:00:04.714Z";"BUTTON";3003926837969;"v01162450701"
```

Finally, you'll be able to load it as a CSV file - and maybe you will have to then normalise everything again: `tripId`seems to be a dependent structure ....

Good luck

Marco the Sane